# How to retrieve data from state address/validate from sawtooth

Tags: javascript, mongodb, blockchain, hyperledger-sawtooth

I've build a login form where i saved my data gets saved in mongoDB, do i save it to sawtooth/load from sawtooth state instead of MongoDB from which i can retrieve to client side. (new to blockchain)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what you are trying to do. I think you are saving authentication credentials after a user login with a password or some other method. The application just stores the credentials and remembers the authentication.

The credentials can be stored in memory, a file, or a database (such as mongodb). Do not store passwords in the clear (unencrypted) on a file or database.

If, however, you have a blockchain application that creates and validates login credentials, the new login would be stored on the blockchain.